# character to integer array

Tags: c++, c

The code below stores values in character array and outputs the integer value . can you please tell me how is it possible?

```
int main()
{ 
   char p;
   char buf[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,9,8};
   p=(buf+1)[5];
   printf("%d",p);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: because `"%d"` expects an integer. You might want to [learn more about those specifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string)

Comment: And a `char` is an 8-bit integer that is *sometimes* interpreted as a character using an ASCII/other table...Sometimes not.  Sometimes it's *just* an 8-bit integer.

Comment: Try setting a character to 'G' (`char g = 'G';`)  Printf it using `%d` like you've done above.  Google `ascii table` and pull up one of the images.  Note the decimal code for `G` and the output of your program.

Comment: I think/guess you are trying to write the character representation i.e                         
 `char buf[10]={'1','2','3','4','5','6','9','8'};` rather than what you have done & represent those characters into integer forms not their integer values. Example '1' as 1 not '1's ASCII value?

Comment: Because a `char` is promoted to `int` when passed to the variadic function `printf`. BTW you forgot to post the program output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p=(buf+1)[5];
```

is the same as

```
p=*(buf+1+5);
```

and the same as

```
p=*(buf+6);
```

and the same as

```
p=buf[6];
```

So look at `buf`

```
char buf[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,9,8};
              ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
              0 1 2 3 4 5 6
                          ^
                          ^
                        The element read
```

So `p` is set equal to 9

and therefore

```
printf("%d",p);
```

prints 9

This is because `%d` means "print integer value" and any integer with size less than int (like a char) is promoted (aka converted) to int when calling `printf`

Comment: I believe a link to the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table is also a good idea. Just thinking it may be important to specify that `char x = '1'` and `char x=1` is not the same.

Comment: @SigveKarolius ASCII is completely irrelevant here. The code only uses numbers. Remember the type "char" is just an integer

Comment: Certainly true, I was merely thinking the confusion could be that the person was wondering why they did not get the "ascii" value of '1'. Not sure why I thought this.

Comment: Does this answer the question as to why a `char` is output as `int`? It is not about array indexing?

Comment: @WeatherVane I would think so... do you think the answer is to explain what `%d` means?

Comment: Is a better answer!

Answer (score 1):

> The code below stores values in character array and outputs the
>   integer value . can you please tell me how is it possible?

```
int main()
{ 
   char p;
   char buf[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,9,8};
   p=(buf+1)[5];
   printf("%d",p);
   return 0;
}
```

`buf` is a pointer that points to the memory location that is the beginning of the declared array.

`(buf + 1)[5]` is really just `*(buf + 6)` which is to say the value stored at the memory location `buf + 6`

This line `p=(buf + 1)[5]` assigns the value stored at the memory location `buf + 6` to `p`

This is printed out as an integer with this line `printf("%d\n",p);`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you store integers in a character array. That means you are currently storing the ascii values of the characters. If you want to get the actual characters you have to change the printf format from "%d" (for printing integers) to "%c" (for printing characters)